# How to see current uber credits using the api

Tags: uber-api

I am applying a promotion code to my uber account using the patch /me endpoint, but i want to verify that the credits actually posted to my account. How do i retreive the current credit balance on my account?

Comment: Reading the [Uber API documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs), I think it's not possible do direct retrive the current credit balance from user

Answer (score 0):

As of now the Rider API don't provide a way to fetch the Uber Credit Balance, but you can check the rider's [payment methods](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/payment-methods-get) added to their Uber account, this API also provide `last_used` payment method's UID
So if the last payment method was completed user's credit balance you might have some luck there.
I haven't tried this particular user case myself, but you feel free to try this.

Example API call

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/payment-methods'
```

Example Response

```
{
  "payment_methods": [
    {
      "payment_method_id": "5f384f7d-8323-4207-a297-51c571234a8c",
      "type": "baidu_wallet",
      "description": "***53",
    },
    {
      "payment_method_id": "f33847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c",
      "type": "alipay",
      "description": "ga***@uber.com",
    },
    {
      "payment_method_id": "f43847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c",
      "type": "visa",
      "description": "***23"
    },
    {
      "payment_method_id": "517a6c29-3a2b-45cb-94a3-35d679909a71",
      "type": "american_express",
      "description": "***05"
    },
    {
      "payment_method_id": "f53847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c",
      "type": "business_account",
      "description": "Late Night Ride"
    }
  ],
  "last_used": "f53847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c"
}
```